# TCPDF keep together function to keep content on 1 page (PDF generation)

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm wondering if there's a keep together function for TCPDF. I have one for FPDF, but I can't get it to work in TCPDF.

Here's how I see it working within the PDF generation code:

```
// ... PDF code/stuff

// while not kept together
    // add PDF stuff that should be kept together

// .. more PDF code/stuff
```

I'm thinking the function would return false if the a new page was added, roll back and then do the while loop again.

I do have the following working, but I'd rather it was in a function/method of TCPDF so it was more reusable:

```
$pdf->startTransaction();
$block_page = $pdf->getPage();
$print_block = 2; // max 2 tries

while ($print_block > 0) {
    // do PDF stuff

    if ($pdf->getPage() == $block_page) {
        $print_block = 0;
    } else {
        // rollback
        $pdf = $pdf->rollbackTransaction();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $block_page = $pdf->getPage();
        -- $print_block;
    }
}
```

It would also be cool if it didn't depend on the built in transaction functionality so transactions can be used within the loop, since things like writeHTML() use transactions.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted similar functionality and settled on using transactions. This on TCPDF version 5.9.125.

I inherited my own PDF class from TCPDF and added my own method:

```
public function writeHTMLTogether($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='') {
    $cp =  $this->getPage();
    $this->startTransaction();

    $this->writeHTML($html, $ln, $fill, $reseth, $cell, $align);

    if ($this->getPage() > $cp) {
         $this->rollbackTransaction(true);//true is very important
         $this->AddPage();
         $this->writeHTML($html, $ln, $fill, $reseth, $cell, $align);           
    } else {            
         $this->commitTransaction();            
    }
}
```

Seemed to work fine. Without the true in the rollback it breaks horribly, as writeHTML seems to store lots of properties somewhere.

May not need to create a local variable for current page ($cp) as I think it's stored. But hey.

If you're inheriting to write your own Header and Footer functions anyway, not much extra work.